# get guid id from Microsoft CRM - javascript console

Tags: javascript, console, microsoft-dynamics

Apparently in earlier versions of Microsoft CRM it was possible to get record Guid in detail page of a record (eg: Account, Contact) using Javascript console, using synatax such as

Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
frames[0].Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();

ref: https://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2014/02/17/crm-2013-javascript-to-get-id-of-record/

I am unable to repeat this in CRM 2015.

```
> frames[0].Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
Unable to get property 'entity' of undefined or null reference


> Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
Unable to get property 'entity' of undefined or null reference
```

however:

```
> this
```

gives me dump that includes

USER_GUID: "{98D61030-7513-4EAA-A243-1D29FA99E0A0}",

**Screen shot of IE Console**

[image]

Comment: can you see any errors in javascript console?

Comment: thanks for prompt reply. I added code & error to question.

Comment: When do you call this code? On button click or page load, ...?

Comment: on console. See added image...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is a change due to the new form rendering inside Dynamics CRM (also known as Turbo Forms)

you can try with

```
frames[1].Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
```